# Keeping entered value on html <textarea> with pages having multiple <form>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

My php page consist of a number of textfileds and textareas in which the user can input their details there. these textareas and textfileds are inside a `<form></form>`.so when clicking on submit button all those values are posted (form method=POST ).

there are 2 `<textarea>` named as Permanent Address and Communication address. and also a check box "Communi. address is same as permanent". the check box code is follows

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkadd" onclick="if (this.checked) copyAddress (this.form)"/>
```

this function calls copyaddress function that copy the Permanent address to Communication address `<textarea>`. " copyAddress (this.form) " will copy the value of 1st `<textarea>`(permanent address). so i don't get the value of Permanent address in the page in which i have to POST this value too to the Next Page.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: you have fault in your script coping address or posting values to another page??

Comment: its copying here is the code,                    f.elements['commadd'].value = f.elements['peradd'].value;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this..

```
 <?php
    if($_POST['permaddress'])
    {
        echo $_POST['permaddress'];
        echo $_POST['commaddress'];

    }
    ?>  
  <script>
        function copyAddress()
        {
            if(document.getElementById('checkadd').checked == true)
            {
                document.getElementById('commaddress').value = document.getElementById('permaddress').value;
            }

        }
        </script>
    <form method="post" action="test.php" >
    <textarea rows="30"cols="30" name="permaddress" id="permaddress"></textarea>
    <textarea rows="30"cols="30" name="commaddress" id="commaddress"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkadd" onclick="copyAddress()"/>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```